# Phaser 3 Drops FPS on latest Chrome Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: phaser-framework

Any Idea on the new updates of chrome, where in when opening a web application game on Phaser, there is a huge performance drop and the PC(desktop) slow becoming sluggish.
We tried to convert all are renderer to canvas mode and it solve the problem. Any idea might it cause to WEBGL on Desktop. Does this issue related to the antivirus, we make use of semantic.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I changed type 'AUTO' to 'CANVAS' in GameConfig and it work fine for all browsers.